# Code assist not working right in Eclipse Mars with PDT

Tags: php, eclipse, pdt

I have Eclipse Mars with PDT installed, but code assist is not working right in my opinion.

When I type a function call but don't know the right parameters I would like Eclipse to display these (using a hover, or with pressing CTRL). But this doesn't work, since the hover is not shown *when the code has an error* (there's a red X in front of the line).

This doesn't make sense to me. Of course there's an error, since I don't know the right parameters, so I could not finish the line yet!

Anyone else has this problem too?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue, it turned out I needed to create an New PHP project and then select the path to my existing code.  Once i did that PHP CodeSniffer went to town and my code insight/assist is working as expected.